# How upload File with FTP using c#

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to upload file (byte = 2000) from local to ftp server, but finnaly i finda blank file (0 byte)

```
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {

        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        //int bytesRead;
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

Comment: when i debug i find bytesSent = 0 and byteBuffer = 2000

Comment: "/* Open a File Stream to *Read* the File for Upload */" comment does not match code next to it. Please make sure to review your code before posting. Also consider using `Stream.CopyTo`...

Comment: from web config : <add key="ipFTP" value="ftp://******************/"/>
    <add key="loginFTP" value="***********"/>
    <add key="pwdFTP" value="*********"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `FileMode.Create` to open the local file; however, as the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) states, `FileMode.Create`

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. **FileMode.Create** is equivalent
>   to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew;
>   otherwise, use Truncate. If the file already exists but is a hidden
>   file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

Thus, you're reading from a zero-byte file; in that case, it shouldn't be surprising that zero bytes are being sent to the FTP server.